# Where can I find a schedule for games being run at GenCon?

Tags: convention

I'd like to see what games are available to play in at GenCon. Is there a website with a published schedule or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best resource is the [HighProgrammer](http://gencon.highprogrammer.com/gencon-indy-2011.cgi) web site. They have an interface that's easy to use and search, and you can copy events to your personal calendar. Once you've found the events you want, you can use the [official registration site](https://www.genconreg.com/) to sign up for events. (There's a search engine there, too, but it requires membership and isn't as responsive.)

Answer (score 1):

There's also an iPhone app and I believe an Android app is in development as well.  Closer to GenCon proper they automatically update all the events with availability, times, location, etc.  Pretty useful if you are looking for something on the fly while there.